# Why doesn't my first HTML table column have bold text?

Tags: html, css

My understanding of the `col` tag tells me that the following should style text in my first table column as bold, but this is not happening. What am I doing wrong?

```
<table class="span-12">
    <col style="font-weight: bold;" />
    <col />
    <tr>
        <td>
            Client
        </td>
        <td>
            Apartment Applied Visual Arts
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The table data cells are not descendants of the col element, so they do not inherit any properties from it. See the [columns section of the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#columns).

Answer (score 4):

This is not the correct way of using , but you can try this:

```
<table class="span-12">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Client
        </th>
        <td>
            Apartment Applied Visual Arts
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, you must add some css to it `table.span-12 th {text-align: left;}`

**OR**

```
<style>
table.span-12 .fat {font-weight: bold;}
</style>

<table class="span-12">
    <tr>
        <th class="fat">
            Client
        </th>
        <td>
            Apartment Applied Visual Arts
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 for teaching me that *th* can be a row header as well as a column header.

Answer (score 1):

`col` (and `colgroup`) elements are somewhat special wrt. CSS. Since table rows and cells are not descendants of `col`s, CSS formatting does not inherit from from `col` to cells.

There is however four CSS properties which can be applied to `col` and `colgroup` and which will affect the cells. These are **border**, **background**, **width** and **visibility**. Each have specific algorithms for how the properties are resolved on the cells.

But since `font-weight` is not one of these four properties, it does not have any effect in your example.

Comment: In other words, tables are just plain a stuff-up to be avoided wherever possible :-)

Comment: Not at all, ProfK. Tables are great for what they ware designed to: tabular data, ie. datapoints with relations in two dimensions. The use of cols and colgroups can help make a complex table more readable.