# HTML: Bolding all values in a table column across browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css-tables

I am trying to make the first column of the below HTML table contain bolded text. I am passing the id values for each cell via Javascript and so I cannot type the actual text into the cells and use `<b>` or `<strong>`. My understanding is that I should be able to do this using `style =`, which creates the bolded first row values I want. I tried to implement this for each cell in the first column, but the second and third rows in the first column do not bold.

I've seen other explanations of how to do this, such as switching `<td>` to `<th>` ([Why doesn't my first HTML table column have bold text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982254/why-doesnt-my-first-html-table-column-have-bold-text)) but that seems to really depend on browser defaults.

```
<table style="width:95%; align:center; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; table-layout:fixed;" border="1" cellspacing="3">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:1.25em; font-align:center;">Attributes</td>
        <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:1.25em; font-align:center;">Group A</td>
        <td style="font-weight:bold; font-size:1.25em; font-align:center;">Group B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;" id="cell_attr1"></td>
        <td id="cell_a1"></td>
        <td id="cell_b1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td style="font-weight:bold;" id="cell_attr2"></td>
        <td id="cell_a2"></td>
        <td id="cell_b2"></td>
    </tr>


</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Where is the CSS you have written to try and accomplish this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. This is a survey in Qualtrics where I use a lot of Javascript and assign values to cell_attr1, cell_a1, cell_b1, cell_attr2, cell_a2, cell_b2 using the JS. There is a separate space for the creation of the question/HTML that will populate. No custom CSS.

Comment: You are asking about controlling the STYLE of elements on a page; that is exactly what Cascading STYLE Sheets are for.